# Compiling JavaScript/TypeScript to executable binary

Tags: javascript, build, compilation

How can programs like [`pkg`](https://github.com/vercel/pkg) and [`deno`](https://deno.land/) compile JS/TS to executable? I'm looking at the repo for `pkg` but I can't find the function. For `deno`, I think it's Rust. But for `pkg`, I can't find the function to `compile` and/or `build` JavaScript (and maybe TypeScript)

The source code for `pkg` is mainly JavaScript and there's no C/C++ or whatever low-level language

Comment: Mostly guessing, but looks like `pkg` is using the [`vm` API](https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html#vm_vm_executing_javascript) to compile/save scripts?

Comment: I guess that could be it

Comment: @IanH. After reading the `vm` API, I couldn't find any function that returns bytecode of compiled JavaScript